# How can I add a List to the JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, list, jlabel

I'm writing Java game right now, I have a problem that I have a List which type is Ranking, with the fields name and score, and I would like to add that fields to the JLabel. Method setText() unfortunately doesn't fix. What should I do?

Comment: *"Method setText() unfortunately doesn't fix. What should I do?"* You should consider making and posting a valid and well formatted [mcve], as is, this question might get closed because it lacks it.

Comment: You have a list? Swing offers `JList`!

Comment: Why aren't you accessing the correct list entry and extract the name and score and just hand over to the label? also why you want to solve that with the label. Like @Frakcool pointed out. Give a minimal example to work with.

Answer (score 0):

> with the fields name and score

A JLabel is not designed to display multiple lines of text.

You can format the text using HTML.

Or I would suggest a better approach is to use a `JTable`, which is designed to display data in a row/column format.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

> I have a List which type is Ranking

You may also want to check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of a custom `TableModel` show how you can display your `Ranking` object in a table.